# Angular unit test for deleting item

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have 2 functions which I would like to cover with unit tests, but kind of stuck with implementation:

```
interface ItemList {
  index: number;
  active: boolean;
}

  clickHandler(item: any) {
    const index = this.itemList.indexOf(item);
    if (item.index % 3 !== 0 && index !== -1) {
      this.itemList.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.changeState(index);
    }
  }

  changeState(index) {
    this.itemList[index].active = true;
  }
}
```

This clickHandler function is called on button click.

```
    <button class="btn" (click)="clickHandler(item)">
      {{ item.index }}
    </button>
```

My unit test

```
  it('should clickHandler() be called on button click', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(app, 'clickHandler').withArgs({ index: 0, active: false }); // here I assume I need to pass my fake item object
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const button: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      '.btn'
    );
    button[1].click();
    tick();
    expect(app.clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    console.log(app.itemList[1].active, 'list'); // I assumed to see that itemList[1] is active 
  }));
```

How to handle:

1. Calling clickHandler method
2. Making sure that item % 3 is active
3. Calling changeState method?

Any help hint is appreciated

Comment: try `spyOn(app, 'clickHandler').andCallThrough()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended up with the following, not sure if thats the perfect one so feel free to comment :

```
it('should create the app with 100 elements', () => {
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(app.itemList.length).toBe(app.itemListLength);
  });

  it('should generateData() be called once on ngOnInit', () => {
    spyOn(app, 'generateData');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(app.generateData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should have 100 buttons', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const buttons: HTMLElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(
      By.css('.btn')
    );
    const buttonsLength = buttons.length;
    expect(buttonsLength).toBe(app.itemListLength);
  });

  it('item list should have 99 items when item with %3 !==0', fakeAsync(() => {
    const itemIndex = 1;
    spyOn(app, 'clickHandler').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const buttons: HTMLElement[] = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      '.btn'
    );
    buttons[itemIndex].click();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(app.clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(app.itemList.length).toBe(app.itemListLength - 1);
  }));

  it('item should have active class if item %3 === 0', fakeAsync(() => {
    const itemIndex = 2;
    const expectedBackgroundColor = 'rgb(122, 152, 236)';
    spyOn(app, 'clickHandler').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const buttons: HTMLElement[] = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      '.btn'
    );
    buttons[itemIndex].click();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const item = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.active')).nativeElement;
    expect(app.clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(app.itemList.length).toBe(app.itemListLength);
    expect(app.itemList[itemIndex].active).toBe(true);
    expect(getComputedStyle(item).backgroundColor).toEqual(
      expectedBackgroundColor
    );
  }));
```